# android one signal duplicate notification

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I use One signal for a few days I was actually doing data push since I do not necessarily create notifications at all. But for a few hours when I send a notification I get two.
I have implemented only the service that extends NotificationExtenderService and redefined the onNotificationProcessing method, although I do not put any code to create a notification once I send one from my back office the notification still creates.
Thank you in advance for your answers and sorry for my English

Comment: This is what I found in the official documentation:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/v5.0/docs/duplicated-notifications
But I still have this issue.